# How do I create a form to search a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

Basically how would I create a form to search only within a custom post type?

Answer (score 3):

just add

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post type name" />
```

to your search form and obviously  replace post type name with your custom post type name.

and to make sure that only your custom post type return as results add:

```
function mySearchFilter_0987($query) {
    $post_type = $_GET['post_type'];
    if (!$post_type) {
        $post_type = 'any';
    }
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', $post_type);
    };
    return $query;
};

add_filter('pre_get_posts','mySearchFilter_0987');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: not working, nothing displayed

Comment: make sure you have the post_type correctly spelled. I was having the same issue only to remember there was no "s" at the end of my post_type.

I also got nothing found when I used the function provided above. Just the `<input>` revision works fine.